# MVC Html.EditorFor have type number, but return string[]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, binding, editorfor

I am probably missing something I should know, but my knowledge of c# and mvc have some weak spots.

The problem is that I am trying to create and I pretty much have everything solved except this problem.

I have this code in View model:

```
public object SettingValue
    {
        get 
        {
            //Some code

            return Convert.ChangeType(value, _type); 
        }
        set 
        {
            ViewModel.Setting = new KeyValuePair<string, object>(ViewModel.Setting.Key, value); 
        }
    }
```

and in View

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.Raw("Value")
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SettingValue)
            @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SettingData)*@
        </div>
    </div>
```

which for example generates this html in case the SettingValue value is type of int

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="SettingValue" name="SettingValue" type="number" value="0" />
```

The exact problem is that the value in set should be int but it return (ViewModel.Setting.Key, **value**) not as object or int but as string[1] with the number as string

Thank for help!

Comment: Of course it does - because its `object` (not `int`). What are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: Hi, I am expecting (and need) the value to be object, but it always return array of strings (string[1]). I am using the KeyValuePair elsewhere and and parsing the object to int, string and ect,

Comment: But `string[#]` is how `object` needs to be represented. Typeof `object` means it could be anything - an `int, a `string` or an `array` or values. So the only way it can be bound is to use `string[]` (and its `string[1]` because your posting 1 value)

Comment: So every type will be posted back as string[#]? If yes, I can handle it this way.

Comment: Yes. If its a single value (`int`, `string` etc) then there will be one item in the collection